# Ubuntu 22.04 force ethernet to 100Mbit/s

Tags: networking, 22.04, netplan

Since upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 my NIC tries to connect with 1Gbit/s, but due to cable issues max 100Mbit/s works stable.

How to force NIC to 100Mbit/s permanently the proper way, meaning by not changing entire Ubuntu system?

ethtool would read like `ethtool -s enp1s0f0 speed 100 duplex full autoneg off`,
but this gets lost during reboot.

I found those hints how to configure static IP with netplan, i.e. copy the default one into 02-static-ip.yaml and make your changes. But those examples only showed how to change information, that are provided by the DHCP mainly,but nothing about how to change to fixed link speed.

Comment: Is it a desktop or a sever?

Comment: This is a Desktop PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using NM CLI.

Check the name of your connection by

```
nmcli c show
```

If your connection is "Wired Connection 1", run:

```
nmcli c edit "Wired connection 1"
goto ethernet
set auto-negotiate no
set speed 100
set duplex full
back
save persistent
quit
```

Disconnect and connect the interface. You are done!

Comment: It looks like they removed it from Gnome :-(

Comment: Yes, already under 20.04.

Comment: I checked it. Now it really works. Duplex needs to be set.

Comment: Went back to Ubuntu to try out above solution, and while running nmcli and failed with missing parameters, the link came upwith 1Gbit/s.

Took photo of provided solution, in case i will have issue back during next reboot.

For the moment i can't neither confirm nor disagree that above provided solution works for.

Still one question open:

Is there a config file in which i can configure the link?

Comment: What do you mean by "failed with missing parameters"?

Comment: "failed with missing parameters";

when running nmcli first, i didn't have the connection name, as Gnome didn't show anything in the profile name. I was directed to "man nmcli", found "nmcli general", and ran this twice.

As non-rootit showed "connectivity no", and right afterwrads, as root, this changed to "full".

Will check this several times during next days to see, if 1Gbit/s is now stable and comes up fast.

In Windows, forcing to 100Mbit/s improved situation very much, as it connects drectly w/ 100Mbit/s )not a big of a loss, when only internet router w/ 50Mbit/s is connected.)

Comment: You an get the name by `nmcli c show`